# Using itemClickListener to pass data from api call to another fragment

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, bundle, pass-data

I have a list of data from my API call into my `RecyclerView`. I have an `itemClickListener` interface that opens a new fragment with item image and details.

When I click on the item, I need to pass data to the 2nd fragment and it's adapter. How will it work?

Do I need to send this data with a bundle and then make another API call inside my 2nd fragment? Or just the bundle with data which I can use without an additional API call?

This is my model:

```
public class Products {

    private String productId;
    private String productName;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String longDescription;
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("productImage")
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("reviewRating")
    private double rating;
    private int reviewCount;
    private boolean inStock;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public String getLongDescription() {
        return longDescription;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public int getReviewCount() {
        return reviewCount;
    }

    public boolean isInStock() {
        return inStock;
    }
}
```

this is my MainFragment:

```
 private void setBundle(int position) {
    args = new Bundle();
    String[] clickedItem = {apiProducts.get(position).getImage(),
            apiProducts.get(position).getLongDescription(),
            String.valueOf(apiProducts.get(position).isInStock())};
    args.putStringArray("Item", clickedItem);
}

private void productsClickListener() {

    if (apiObjectAdapter != null) {

        apiObjectAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {

                setBundle(position);
                setDetailsFragment(args);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My adapter:

```
public class ApiObjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ApiObjectAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.product_name)
    public TextView name;
    @BindView(R.id.product_rating)
    public TextView rating;
    @BindView(R.id.product_price)
    public TextView price;


    public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);
        this.parentView = view;

        try {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onItemClick(view, getLayoutPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bundle 
form sender put data as

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in next receiver receive as

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

more detail about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Comment: I'm not sending int in my bundle. I need to send String imageURL and String description. Should I use parseable instead?

Comment: You can use parcelable also, but it will be better if you send the productId and then fetch the details in fragment for that paticular product.

Comment: you can also put Stirng info like this one bundle.putString(String key , String value );bundle.putString("imageURL " , "http://myurls.com/imag.png" );bundle.putString("description" , "test product" );

Comment: But should I do api call after I get the bundle?